# Mac Pro Bootcamp issue with windows 10 networking

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, boot-camp, mac-pro

I'm using windows 10 on the latest Mac Pro module with bootcamp with latest stable OSX.

i have two networking issues:

1. I can't connect to wifi networks. it does list them but when I try to connect, it fails.
2. so I use an ethernet cable for now. and it seems that some games doesn't recognize that the internet is working. for example... the game `dayz` on steam. It can't find any dayz server as if I don't have any internet access.

I've been told to go to the control panel and to uninstall network drivers, scan for changes and let it reinstall everything. it didn't resolve the issue.

I also tried removing bootcamp, re-creating the partition, reinstalled windows 10 but the problem persists.

I've also been told to try and install the drivers manually... Welp after bootcamp installed the relevant drivers I don't have access to these files anymore so no idea how to do that.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Boot Camp Assistant is the only place to get the driver packages - if you re-created & re-installed without it, you threw them out. If you used a USB key initially, they should be on there.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks. ok.. i'll try reinstalling bootcamp again and this time to select to store drivers in usb. I can't really remember that I had an option to do that. are you sure ?

Comment: BCA does it afaik, at creation; it has to put them somewhere where the Windows OS can find them - it's been a very long time since I did it, my current BC is a migration from my last Mac, so I'm a bit hazy perhaps. One thing I know for certain is you cannot get them from anywhere else than BCA.

Comment: @Tetsujin - awesome. i'll check it out later today and let you know.